# Generator that is based on another generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, yield-keyword

My task is actually quite simple, but I cannot figure out how to achieve it. I am intending to use this in my ML algo, but let's simplify the example. Suppose there is a generator like the following:

```
nums = ((i+1) for i in range(4))
```

The above, will yield us `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`.

Suppose that the above generator returns individual "samples". I want to write a generator method that will batch them up. Suppose, the batch size is `2`. So if this new method is called:

```
def batch_generator(batch_size):
    do something on nums
    yield batches of size batch_size
```

And then the output of this batch generator would be: `1` and `2` and then `3` and `4`. Tuples/lists does not matter. What matters is to how to return these batches. I found this `yield from` keyword that was introduced in Python 3.3, but it seems it is not useful in my case.

And obviously, if we had `5` nums instead of `4`, and `batch_size` is `2`, we would omit the last yielded value from the first generator.

Comment: See the `grouper` recipe in the `itertools` documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My own solution for this could be,

```
nums = (i+1 for i in range(4))

def giveBatch(gen, numOfItems):
    try:
        return [next(gen) for i in range(numOfItems)]
    except StopIteration:
        pass

giveBatch(nums, 2)
# [1, 2]
giveBatch(nums, 2)
# [3, 4]
```

---

Another solution is to use `grouper` as @Bharel mentioned. I have compared the time it takes to run both of these solutions. There is not much of a difference. I guess it can be neglected.

```
from timeit import timeit

def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

nums = (i+1 for i in range(1000000))

wrappedGiveBatch = wrapper(giveBatch, nums, 2)
timeit(wrappedGiveBatch, number=1000000)
# ~ 0.998439

wrappedGrouper = wrapper(grouper, nums, 2)
timeit(wrappedGrouper, number=1000000)
# ~ 0.734342
```

Comment: love it. And StopIteration would be thrown if there are not enough samples for the batch. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Yes, I was just adding that, you are welcome :)

Comment: or not thrown :)) haha

Comment: 25% faster iteration is quite a bit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Under [**itertools**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) you have a code snippet which does just that:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Instead of calling a method every time, you have an iterator that returns batches, much more efficient, faster, and handles corner cases like running out of data too soon without losing it.

Answer (score 0):

This was exactly what I needed:

```
def giveBatch(numOfItems):
    nums = (i+1 for i in range(7))

    while True:
        yield [next(nums) for i in range(numOfItems)]
```

Comment: Glad you have found your solution, still instead of defining `nums` static, it's better to pass it to the function and do your stuff in a more generic and flexible way. That way you can use `giveBatch` with any generator.

Comment: True, I will refactor :)